# PrimeNG menubar start directive not displayed in unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine, primeng

I am writing Jasmine tests on my component containing PrimeNG’s menubar.  I am using the **start** template directive as follows:

```
<p-menubar id='menubar' [model]='items'>
  <ng-template pTemplate='start'>
    <span id='menubarTitle' class='nsg-primary-color nsg-bold'>{{ title }}:</span>
  </ng-template>
</p-menubar>
```

I am attempting to test the existence of the **start** template directive.  To make it easier, I added an **id** to the span tag and try to get the span element:

```
it('should render start menubar title ...', () => {
  // given / when
  const expectedMenuTitle = 'Net Incident:';
  const menubarTitle: HTMLSpanElement = fixture.debugElement.query(
    By.css( '#menubarTitle' )).nativeElement;
  // then
  expect( menubarTitle.innerText ).toEqual( expectedMenuTitle );
});
```

But I am getting the following Jasmine error message:

```
MenuComponent > should render start menubar title ...
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null
```

In playing around with the Jasmine rendering (id='menubar'), it seems as if the **div.p-menubar-start.ng-star-inserted** element is not displayed.  In my application the **start** text is displayed.  When I looked at the source on GitHub, it seem that PrimeFaces does not test this in the unit tests.  What to do?

The abbreviated spec is as follows:

```
// File: menu.component.spec.ts
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
//
import { Menubar, MenubarModule } from 'primeng/menubar';
//
import { MenuComponent } from './menu.component';
//
describe('MenuComponent', () => {
  let component: MenuComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MenuComponent>;
  //
  beforeEach( waitForAsync( () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MenubarModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        Menubar,
        MenuComponent
      ]
    } );
    TestBed.compileComponents( );
  }));
  //
  beforeEach( fakeAsync( () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MenuComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    tick( 1000 );
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }) );
  // two tests removed ...
  it('should render start menubar title ...', () => {
    // given / when
    const expectedMenuTitle = 'Net Incident:';
    const menubarTitle: HTMLSpanElement = fixture.debugElement.query(
      By.css( '#menubarTitle' )).nativeElement;
    // then
    expect( menubarTitle.innerText ).toEqual( expectedMenuTitle );
  });
  //
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add the following imports:

```
  import { SharedModule } from 'primeng/api';
  ...
      imports: [
        MenubarModule,
        SharedModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
```

The more complete spec is as follows:

```
// File: menu.component.spec.ts
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
//
import { SharedModule } from 'primeng/api';
import { Menubar, MenubarModule } from 'primeng/menubar';
//
import { MenuComponent } from './menu.component';
//
describe('MenuComponent', () => {
  let component: MenuComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MenuComponent>;
  //
  beforeEach( waitForAsync( () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MenubarModule,
        SharedModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        Menubar,
        MenuComponent
      ]
    } );
    TestBed.compileComponents( );
  }));
  //
  beforeEach( fakeAsync( () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MenuComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    tick( 1000 );
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable();
  }) );
  // ... two tests removed
  it('should render start menubar title ...', () => {
    // given / when
    const expectedMenuTitle = 'Net Incidents:';
    const menubarTitle: HTMLSpanElement = fixture.debugElement.query(
      By.css( '#menubarTitle' )).nativeElement;
    // then
    expect( menubarTitle.innerText ).toEqual( expectedMenuTitle );
  });
  //
});
```

Comment: importing SharedModule solved the issue, thank you

Answer (score 0):

By.CSS might be for CSS class names, You can try By.ID

Comment: By.Id is not an option in the intellisense for By.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put `MenuBarModule` in your `imports` array in `TestBed.configureTestingModule({})` so your component knows how to paint it.

Something like this:

```
import {MenubarModule} from 'primeng/menubar';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [MenubarModule,], // can put your other stuff here too
    declaratations: [],
    providers: [],
    schemas: [],    
  }).compileComponents();
```

Edit====
Maybe you're missing a `fixture.detectChanges()` or something `asynchronous` has to take place for it to display. Sometimes it is not queryable by `fixture.debugElement`, you can try `document` or `fixture.nativeElement`. This happened to me before when I was using Ag-Grid.

Try:

```
it('should render start menubar title ...', async (done) => {
  // given / when
  const expectedMenuTitle = 'Net Incident:';
  fixture.detectChanges();
  await fixture.whenStable();
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(fixture.nativeElement); // ensure the nativeElement has 
    // the element you're looking for.
    const element = document.querySelector('#menubarTitle');
    console.log(element); // see if it's queryable by the document element
    const element2 = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#menubarTitle');
    console.log(element2); // see if it's queryable by the fixture element
    const menubarTitle: HTMLSpanElement = fixture.debugElement.query(
    By.css( '#menubarTitle' )).nativeElement;
     // then
    expect( menubarTitle.innerText ).toEqual( expectedMenuTitle );
    done();
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: I already had the MenubarModule imported, but I did add **declarations: [ Menubar, MenuComponent ]**, but no change, still not found.  I even restarted **ng test**.

Comment: Ok, check out my edit. Try using `document.querySelector`, `fixture.nativeElement.querySelector` and play around with `fixture.detectChanges` and `fixture.whenStable` and `setTimeout`.